# How to call a .NET webservice from Android using KSOAP2 and remember that I've logged in successfully

Tags: .net, android, ksoap2

I've successfully (with a lot of help from stack-overflow) written code to call the login (passing username and password) and the correct fields are returned.

I then want to call another function, but the webservice returns a code indicating that I haven't logged in. How do I make the it (the service) remember that I (the client) have logged in?

Is it something to do with cookies?? Sorry if this is a trivial question but I haven't found any relevant answers out there..

--UPDATE-- yes cookies are the way forward, and headerproperty, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of authentication you use. 
For example if your login service create an http session, then your have to pass session cookie received from login to following services.